# How to make a dropdown menu on an Entity Framework template

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for this website I'm working on. It should've been simple coding since it is on Html and CSS, yet what I've done doesn't work. It simply doesn't show when I'm hovering over the text that is supposed to activate the dropdown menu.

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id=" el_pepe">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("maderas", "Productos", "tblProductos") </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#el_pepe {
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#el_pepe *:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: i don't think this question has anything to do whit entity-framework or asp.net-mvc, consider remove the #

Answer (score 1):

i dont tink you can hover a hidden element, you may need to hide the child only and trigger the hover on the parent

like

```
#el_pepe ul li div {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#el_pepe ul li:hover div {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

but im not sure what are you trying to achieve, explain a little more your goal.

also remove the space on your id

let me asume that el_pepe is a `<div>` that has a hamburger icon or somthing and your `<ul>` is the menu hidden, then you must hide the `<ul>` only

somthing like

```
#el_pepe ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#el_pepe:hover ul.nav.navbar-nav{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

here you have an example:
[css menu](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `div class="dropdown-menu"` should come under `ul class="nav navbar-nav"` not the other way, since you're using bootstrap classes.

And you can open the dropdown on hover from CSS as follows, if the html structure is fixed.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

And this should be the html structure

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's a working bootstrap v4 [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bw6exua0/1/) and v3 [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cum2bpkL/).